# "Gambiarra" em C# com XML, gostaria de sugestões para melhoria

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

Tenho esse código sem a "gambiarra", que retorna a lista com os valores repetidos:

```
var s = (from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("pais")
                           let Nomepais = p.Element("nome-pais").Value
                           let nomeconsulado = p.Element("consulados").Element("consulado").Element("nome-consulado").Value
                           let endereco = p.Element("consulados").Element("consulado").Element("endereco").Value
                           let cep = p.Element("consulados").Element("consulado").Element("cep").Value
                           from t in xmlDoc.Descendants("telefones")
                           let telefone = t.Elements("telefone").Select(f => f.Value).ToList()     
                           from e in xmlDoc.Descendants("emails")
                           let email = e.Elements("email").Select(m => m.Value).ToList()
                           where Nomepais == SSP.Consulado.pais
                           select new ListaConsulado.Consulado()
                           {             
                               NomePais = Nomepais,
                               Cep = "Cep: " + cep,
                               Endereco = endereco,
                               NomeConsulado = nomeconsulado,
                               Telefone = telefone,
                               Email = email
                           }
                           ).ToList();
lista.ItemsSource = s;
```

Antes dessa tela, tem os países:

[image: Paises]

Que quando selecionado um, vai para a lista de Consulados

[image: "Gambiarra"]

E esse, com a "gambiarra":

```
lista.ItemsSource = s.GroupBy(t => t.NomeConsulado).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

[image: Sem "Gambiarra"]

**Queria saber, se tem um jeito de melhorar isso, por que acho que desse jeito não é o correto. Sugestões?**

`ListaConsulado.cs`

```
class ListaConsulado
    {

        public class Paises
        {
            public Paises()
            {
                this.NomePais = string.Empty;
                Consulados = new List<Consulado>();
            }
            public Paises(String NomePais)
            {
                this.NomePais = NomePais;
                Consulados = new List<Consulado>();
            }
            public Paises(String NomePais, List<Consulado> Consulados)
            {
                this.NomePais = NomePais;
                this.Consulados = Consulados;
            }

            public Paises(List<Consulado> Consulados)
            {
                this.NomePais = string.Empty;
                this.Consulados = Consulados;
            }
            public String NomePais { get; set; }
            public IList<Consulado> Consulados { get; set; }
        }

        public class Consulado
        {
            public string NomePais { get; set; }
            public string NomeConsulado { get; set; }
            public string Endereco { get; set; }
            public string Cep { get; set; }
            public string Fax { get; set; }
            public string Geral { get; set; }
            public string Honorario { get; set; }
            public string UrlSite { get; set; }
            public string NomeChefia { get; set; }
            public string Observacao { get; set; }
            public string Expediente { get; set; }
            public string Jurisdicao { get; set; }
            public List<string> Telefone { get; set; }
            public List<string> Email { get; set; }
            public BitmapImage NomeImgBandeira { get; set; }
        }
   }
}
```

`XML:`

```
<paises>

<pais>
        <nome-pais>Austrália</nome-pais>    
        <consulados>        
            <consulado>
                <nome-consulado>Consulado-Geral da Austrália em São Paulo - SP </nome-consulado>        
                <endereco>Alameda Santos, 700 - 9º andar conjunto 92, Cerqueira César, São Paulo-SP</endereco>      
                <cep>01418-100</cep>                
                <fax>(11) 3171-2889</fax>
                <geral>1</geral>
                <honorario>0</honorario>
                <nome_img_bandeira>flag_australia</nome_img_bandeira>
                <url-site></url-site>
                <emails></emails>
                <nome-chefia>Mark Argar</nome-chefia>
                <telefones>
                    <telefone>(11) 2112-6200</telefone>
                    <telefone>(11) 2112-6215 </telefone>
                    <telefone>(11) 3171-2851 </telefone>
                </telefones>
                <observacao>Auxílio a cidadãos australianos: (0xx11) 3171-2851</observacao>
                <expediente></expediente>
                <jurisdicao></jurisdicao>
            </consulado>
        </consulados>
    </pais>

<pais>
        <nome-pais>Áustria</nome-pais>
        <consulados>        
            <consulado>
                <nome-consulado>Consulado-Geral da Áustria em São Paulo - SP</nome-consulado>       
                <endereco>Av. Dr. Cardoso de Melo 1470 - Conj. 711 - Ed. Net Office - Vila Olímpia, São Paulo-SP</endereco>     
                <cep>04548-005</cep>                
                <fax>(11) 3926-6798</fax>
                <geral>1</geral>
                <honorario>0</honorario>
                <nome_img_bandeira>flag_austria</nome_img_bandeira>
                <url-site></url-site>
                <emails>
                    <email>consuladosp@austria.org.br</email>
                </emails>
                <nome-chefia>Dr. Ingomar Lochschmidt (Cônsul), Stefan Nemetz (Vice-Cônsul)</nome-chefia>
                <telefones>
                    <telefone>(11) 3842-7500</telefone>
                </telefones>
                <observacao></observacao>
                <expediente></expediente>
                <jurisdicao></jurisdicao>
            </consulado>
            <consulado>
                <nome-consulado>Consulado-Geral da Áustria em São Paulo - SP - Departamento Comercial</nome-consulado>      
                <endereco>Av. Dr. Cardoso de Melo 1340 - 7º andar - Conj. 71 - Vila Olímpia, São Paulo-SP</endereco>        
                <cep>04548-004</cep>                
                <fax>(11) 3842-5330</fax>
                <geral>1</geral>
                <honorario>0</honorario>
                <nome_img_bandeira>flag_austria</nome_img_bandeira>
                <url-site></url-site>
                <emails>
                    <email>SaoPaulo@advantageaustria.org</email>
                    <email>saopaulo@wko.at</email>
                </emails>
                <nome-chefia>Dr. Ingomar Lochschmidt (Cônsul), Stefan Nemetz (Vice-Cônsul)</nome-chefia>
                <telefones>
                    <telefone>(11) 3044-9944</telefone>
                </telefones>
                <observacao></observacao>
                <expediente></expediente>
                <jurisdicao></jurisdicao>
            </consulado>
        </consulados>
    </pais>     
</paises>
```

`XAML`

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="lstCons"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    LayoutMode="List" 
    IsGroupingEnabled="False"
    Width="456" SelectionChanged="lstCons_SelectionChanged" >
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#111" Background="Transparent" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical"  >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomeConsulado}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Endereco}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cep}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telefone}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </Border>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Sim, teve alteração no XML @FCCDias; Sugiro que você de uma resposta com a solução

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que a unidade do retorno são consulados, fica mais simples se iniciarmos a seleção direto com os consulados, e obter as outras informações, no sentido dos elementos ancestrais ou descendentes, usando os métodos do XElement para obtê-los:

```
var consulados =
    (from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("consulado")
     let p = c.Ancestors("pais").Single()
     let nomepais = p.Element("nome-pais").Value
     where nomepais == SSP.Consulado.pais
     select new ListaConsulado.Consulado
     {
         NomePais = nomepais,
         Cep = "Cep: " + c.Element("cep").Value,
         Endereco = c.Element("endereco").Value,
         NomeConsulado = c.Element("nome-consulado").Value,
         Telefone = c.Descendants("telefone").Select(t => t.Value).ToList(),
         Email = c.Descendants("email").Select(t => t.Value).ToList(),
     }).ToList();
```

Ancestrais:

- somente o elemento ancestral `pais` é necessário, podemos chegar até ele usando o método `Ancestors`:

  ```
  let p = c.Ancestors("pais").Single()
  ```

Descendentes:

- Para pegar os descendentes, podemos usar o método `Descendants`:

  ```
  Telefone = c.Descendants("telefone").Select(t => t.Value).ToList(),
  Email = c.Descendants("email").Select(t => t.Value).ToList(),
  ```

Comment: Então, desse seu jeito, ele traz todo os consulados, sendo que eu quero que traz o consulado do pais que eu quero. Por exemplo: eu seleciono o item "Áustria", eu só vou querer os consulados da "Áustria"

Comment: Realmente, faltou o `where`... vou corrigir.

Comment: Coloquei o `where` assim como estava na sua questão... de forma que agora, será possível filtrar pelo nome do país.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado!

Comment: Miguel, pra eu adicionar os telefones no TextBlock, o que eu preciso fazer? Editei a pergunta com o `XAML`

Comment: Você pode criar uma outra propriedade na classe `ListaConsulado.Consulado` que concatena as strings da lista em uma única string, e então usar essa propriedade no XAML.

Comment: **Na classe:** `public string TelefoneStr { get { return string.Join("; ", this.Telefone); } }` **no XAML:** `<TextBlock Text="{Binding TelefoneStr}" ... "/>`

Comment: Miguel, surgiu a necessidade de colocar tipo: **Telefones:** `14141414; 656656565; 65656565...`. Como faço pra adicionar o texto "Telefones" antes dos numeros?

Comment: Se você usou a sugestão de criar uma propriedade `TelefoneStr`, basta concatenar a string antes: `public string TelefoneStr { get { return "Telefones: " + string.Join("; ", this.Telefone); } } `

Answer (score 2):

Tenho a impressão que você gostaria de simplesmente preencher a lista com `Pais` contendo a lista de `Consulados`, segue minha sugestão:

```
var lista = (from p in doc.Root.Elements()
        select new ListaConsulado.Paises
        {
            NomePais = p.Element("nome-pais").Value,
            Consulados = (from c in p.Elements("consulados").Elements()
                         select new ListaConsulado.Consulado
                         {
                             NomeConsulado = c.Element("nome-consulado").Value,
                             Endereco = c.Element("endereco").Value,
                             Cep = c.Element("cep").Value,
                             Telefone = c.Descendants("telefone").Select(m => m.Value).ToList(),
                             Email = c.Descendants("email").Select(m => m.Value).ToList()
                         }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez que você utiliza LINQ, o método [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) pode vir a calhar. I.e.:

```
lista.ItemsSource = s.GroupBy(t => t.NomeConsulado).Distinct().ToList();
```

Note que esse método usa a comparação padrão entre objetos para eliminar as duplicatas - ou seja, dois consulados "iguais" podem ser considerados diferentes por serem objetos com referências distintas. Assim, pode ser recomendável também criar um tipo para os consulados, que sobrecarregue o método `Equals` de forma que você consiga distinguir consulados pelos valores dos mesmos.